# Is it possible to commit transaction in BeforeTransportMessage event

Tags: rebus

As in title I wanted to ask is it possible to commit transaction in BeforeTransportMessage event so for example if specific headers occur in TransportMessage I could wrap it in another message and send somewhere else and stop Rebus from futher processing.

I didn't find any real life example of using that event, is there maybe something you could share?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can safely deserialize all incoming message, this is what you can do:

If you're trying to implement a filter that inspects all incoming messages, I suggest you create a "catch-all" message handler, i.e. an implementation of `IHandleMessages<object>`. Let's call it `CatchAllHandler`, although I'm sure you can come up with a better name ;)

Then you can

```
Configure.With(yourFavoriteContainerAdapter)
    .UseMsmq(...)
    .SpecifyOrderOfHandlers(o => o.First<CatchAllHandler>())
    .Create()
    .Start();
```

in order to have all incoming messages dispatched to your `CatchAllHandler` before any other handlers. Since it implements `IHandleMessage<object>`, it is capable of handling all incoming messages. Your `CatchAllHandler` can then do something like this:

```
public class CatchAllHandler : IHandleMessages<object> {
    readonly IMessageContext context;
    readonly IBus bus;

    public CatchAllHandler(IMessageContext context, IBus bus) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void Handle(object message) {
        if (MessageHasSpecialHeader(context.Headers)) {
            // forward the current transport message in its entirety
            bus.Advanced.Routing.ForwardCurrentMessage("somewhereElse");

            // abort further processing of the message (i.e. do not
            // dispatch to subsequent handlers in the pipeline)
            context.Abort();
        }
    }

    bool MessageHasSpecialHeader(IDictionary<string, object> headers) {
        // ... look for that special header down here
    }
}
```

If, however, you don't know whether the incoming `byte[]` is good for you, you need to do something else. It's fairly straightforward though to use Rebus' transport implementations without the rest of Rebus, but you'll have to implement the threading model yourself.

The following code is an example (written completely from memory, so you might need to correct some small bits) on what such a worker thread might look like if you're using MSMQ:

```
volatile bool _keepWorking = true;

public void ThreadLoop() {
    using(var transport = new MsmqMessageQueue("inputQueueName")) {
        while(_keepWorking) {
            using(var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
            using(var context = new AmbientTransactionContext())
            {
                var message = transport.ReceiveMessage(context);
                if (message == null) {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); //< don't punish queues too much
                    continue;
                }

                var destination = GetDestinationBasedOnWhatever(message);

                transport.Send(destination, message.ToForwardableMessage());

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd need a separate queue for this special kind of [content-based router](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ContentBasedRouter.html) to work though. Do you think that would work for you?

Comment: unfortunately my problem is that I need to do the checks before message is deserialized because I want to check if assemblies required for deserialization are available, that's why I asked about the event. I should have mention it earlier, sorry about that, but I'm sure the code you posted will be helpful in future :)

Comment: independently from previous comment for future readers should that handler be registred like that: adapter.Register(() => new CatchAllHandler(bus, MessageContext.GetCurrent())) ?

Comment: unfortunately, there's currently no _easy_ way to forward the message without attempting to deserialize it - but there is another option which I'll update my answer with... BRB

Comment: thank you, it's nice idea to take transport abstraction from rebus and use it directly. The other way I can think of would be using Rebus as usually with object that would be transport for the real object (the real one could be inside byte[] property i.e.) so I could control deserialization of the real object inside Rebus handler. Do you think that could make sense too?

Comment: your solution is more clear though, don't you agree? :)

Comment: for future readers you please tell if registration of CatchAllHandler I posted above is correct?

Comment: I would prefer my solution because it doesn't require changes to the format of the messages. Moreover, with a little extra work, you could generalize your implementation of my solution which would give you a generic router that can route messages based on headers - that could turn out to be handy in other situations as well

Comment: great, I can actually add that generic router to my Rebus fork :-)

Comment: your `BuiltinContainerAdapter` catch-all handler registration looks fine to me :)